# Type 'MutableRefObject<undefined>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement> | undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have set up a custom hook which gets a `ref` object and observes it:

```
import { useState, useEffect, MutableRefObject } from "react";

const UseOnScreen = (ref: MutableRefObject<undefined>) => {
  const [isIntersecting, setIntersecting] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) =>
      setIntersecting(entry.isIntersecting)
    );
    if (ref.current) {
      observer.observe(ref.current);
    }
  });
  return isIntersecting;
};
export default UseOnScreen;
```

Next, in my page component, I have declared a `ref` using `useRef()`:

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import UseOnScreen from "../hooks/UseOnScreen";
import About from "./about";

export default function Home() {
  const aboutRef = useRef();
  const aboutRefValue = UseOnScreen(aboutRef);

  return (
     <>
         {/* other components */}
         <div ref={aboutRef}>{aboutRefValue && <About />}</div>
     </>
  );
}
```

This gives the following error:

```
Type 'MutableRefObject<undefined>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement> | undefined'.
  Type 'MutableRefObject<undefined>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>'.
    Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'HTMLDivElement | null'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(138, 9): The expected type comes from property 'ref', which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'
```

The strange fact about this error is, though this gives an error in my editor, the code still works as expected.
I tried setting the type of ref object to `LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement> | undefined`, but the error still persists.

I would like to get rid of this error in my editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `MutableRefObject<undefined>`, you are saying I want the ref of `undefined`; that's the problem. Change it to `MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | null>` and also update your `useRef` call, like so:

```
const useOnScreen = (ref: MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | null>) => {
  const [isIntersecting, setIntersecting] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) =>
      setIntersecting(entry.isIntersecting)
    );
    if (ref.current) {
      observer.observe(ref.current);
    }
  });
  return intersecting;
};
export default useOnScreen;
```

```
export default function Home() {
  const aboutRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const aboutRefValue = useOnScreen(aboutRef);

  return (
    <>
      {/* other components */}
      <div ref={aboutRef}>
        {aboutRefValue && <div>Your about was here</div>}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image]